# Test if btrfs subvolume exists

Tags: bash, backup, btrfs, ubuntu-18.04, snapshot

I have a problem in a bash procedure, which should port my old rsync disk backup (and archive) to my future btrfs snapshot backup.

I want to use the line:

```
 # btrfs subvolume snapshot /targetdir/@monthly.9 /targetdir/@monthly.8
```

If the snapshot /targetdir/@monthly.8 does not jet exist, then it gets created, as I want to.

But if /targetdir/@monthly.8 was there already, then /targetdir/@monthly.8/@onthly.9 gets created instead.

I am missing here a test for existence, say:

```
# [[ -bsnap <snap-path> ]] # =TRUE if <snap-path> exists and is a snap!
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: My btrfs-progs v4.4 here on ubuntu 16.4 (dayly up to date) seems to overinterprete the man btrfs-subvolume, that says: "... snapshot [-r] <source> <dest>|[<dest>/]<name> ...  If only <dest> is given, the subvolume will be named the basename of <source>." It seems to add imlicitly: "If <dest>/name exists already, then create <dest>/<name>/$(basename <source>)". I would call it a bug, or an evil feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't want to run `btrfs subvolume snapshot …` if `/targetdir/@monthly.8` exists, regardless what it is. Just test if it exists:

```
[ -e /targetdir/@monthly.8 ]
```

or doesn't exist

```
[ ! -e /targetdir/@monthly.8 ]
```

whatever is more useful. If it exists when it shouldn't then `btrfs subvolume delete` it. Only if this command returns `ERROR: not a subvolume` do worry what else the object is. I advise you to organize your workflow, subvolumes, mountpoints, directories and their permissions in a way that `@monthly.8` could only be a subvolume.

---

But if you really need to know

```
btrfs subvolume show /targetdir/@monthly.8
```

will succeed if it's a subvolume; it will fail otherwise. Example:

```
btrfs subvolume show /targetdir/@monthly.8 &>/dev/null && echo "It's a subvolume!"
```

Comment: I would like to add my command as a further option in your answer. Then I woud delete my answer, in order to stremline the argument a little. I don't think I am soo picky!

Comment: @prometheos See [*Can I answer my own question?*](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) Our answers can coexist. You can accept your own answer if it suits *you* better.

Comment: Sorry @Kamil Maciorowski that so much time has passed before me to accept the answer. Just now I urgently need this feature, and this answer is the most useful I can think of  to wrap into a function, like - in bash: `probe-subvolume() { btrfs subvolume show $1  &>/dev/null && { true; } || { false; }; } `

Comment: @prometheos It's OK. Just curious: in what aspect is `foo && { true; } || { false; }` better than just `foo`?

Comment: " oh yes, I see! The cut-and-paste-devil hit me, somehow. I had first coded for textual ourput, like ` ...|| echo "$1 is either not a subvolume or not existant."; false; } `. Here I  used "false" for having the right return code: echo <text> would be allways "sucessful". Then I found that "weniger ist mehr" and removed the text, leaving the rest. You are right: even less ist even better. My shortened code (gets so short that one could do whithout the function!): ` probe-subvolume() { btrfs subvolume show $1 &>/dev/null; } `  For @Kamil Maciorowski

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Kamil Maciorowski is good. But let me concentrate onto the existence test.

Say I am debugging, and I need to repeat a try, and the target snapshot was already there. Then I was very cautious and sat "bash -e" (i.e. the first error exits my shell. Remember that I must run it as root...). Then I prefer a command that tells me what happened, and then exits. Therefore I do:

```
    btrfs subvolume list  /targetdir/@monthly.9 | grep @monthly.8 &&  echo "$0 ERROR: snapshot /targetdir/@monthly.8 exists already!" && exit
```

Command "subvolume list " gives no error and lists them all. Then I filter as I need and make my decisions.

Comment: Oops! Why did my answer jump to the top? I tought they go chronologically, if they have no votes.

Comment: Chronologically if you click "oldest" just above the first answer. This is per user preference and the site is not a forum.

Comment: I hope you are aware it does not test exactly for `/targetdir/@monthly.8`. I think any subvolume with `@monthly.8` in its path (I mean internal path in the filesystem) will trigger `echo`, even if this particular subvolume is not reachable in your directory tree at the moment. My solution, on the other hand, tests exactly the object appearing as `/targetdir/@monthly.8` in the directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
function btrfsCreateSVIfNotExist ()
{
    # parameters: $1 the dest/name of the subvolume (what you'd pass to btrfs subvolume create, e.g. /home/MYSUBVOLNAME)
    # creates a btrfs subvolume under dest/ if it doesn't already exist
    if ! btrfs subvolume show "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        btrfs subvolume create "$1"
    fi
}
export -f btrfsCreateSVIfNotExist
```